# Angular 2+ ngx-print add data to the print section

Tags: angular, printing

I'm using ngx-print, I have div container that I'm already print.
I have also object that contains some data.

for example :

```
<div id="print-section"> 
  <span>{{obj.id}}</span>
  <span>{{obj.name}}</span>
</div>

<button printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

what I want to do is to add just for the printing action data, that not displayed at the print-section container.

```
obj={
    id:1,
    name: "david"
    date: "12/15/2019"
 }
```

I mean, when I click on the button it will show me the print-section and the date I have in obj.

I didn't see any examples/documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print website.

thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried just hiding the extra data with css? it will still show up in the print modal: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7eogg

Comment: I did it :) , I just wonder if it has any nice way to do it.

Comment: another way would be to dynamically create the div upon button click.. without attaching to the dom. good luck

Comment: is there a solution for this issue yet?